# HTML5 Adding placeholder attr to LI

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

I need to figure out if it is possible, and how, to be able to have placeholder text like feature on list item elements in html5 `<li>`. It needs to function the same way as placeholder in textfield or textarea i.e. not count as text when li is queried for its contents but yet show when `<li>` is empty.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
<li placeholder="This is the template for your input"/>
```

Can this be done easily? If so, could someone share the best approach?

I am trying to use this inside quill WYSIWYG html editor so may have limited options.

Comment: You can't add a placeholder to li elements Have a look at the documentation. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-placeholder-attribute I would suggest you to use a <label> tag or the title attribute.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Just look at @RGraham answer. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use CSS3, you can make use of the `:empty`, `:after` pseudo selectors in combination with `content`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("li").textContent); // Doesn't see the CSS content
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector("li").textContent = "test";
}, 2000);
```

```css
li:empty:after {
    content: "This is the template for your input";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was going to answer with a pure Javascript approach but this one seems to be more suitable

Comment: Nice one. I was also creating a javascript approach.